# Hiding Form 1 and Show form 2 on Windows Form 1 Load

Tags: c#, winforms

Am a newbie when it come to C# Programming. Here's my trouble:
I want to Show a new Form 2 and Hide Form 1 on the Windows Form 1 Load.

Here's my current codes;

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var Form2 = new Form2();
    Form2.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

My en-counted Error with the current Code:
When Form 1 load its loading Form 2 but it's not hiding itself. `this.Hide` Statement not working, I've try `this.Close` but this will Close the entire software as it's closing the main form.

Can anyone kindly help me with this error.

Comment: You can't hide the form in the Load event, that event fires because the form became visible.  The obvious solution is to change your Main() method and let it create Form2 instead of Form1.

Comment: Yea but I need it this way I know I could simply load the Form 2 from program.cs but doing so will prevent me from doing what I need my software to do.

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34219470/5667732 , @Hans Passant here we go it's not in the Load Event. Thanks for helping me know how this Load Event work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I manage to make this work.

New Codes:
Form 1

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Form2 = new Form2();
        Form2.Show();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.Status == "Form2Visible")
        {
            this.Hide();
        }

    }
```

Explanation:
On the Windows Form 1 Load am showing the the Form 2, then using a timer to verify a Properties.Settings Value. If the Properties.Settings = Form2Visible, Form 1 will Hide. Once am done on Form 2 I simply need to change the Properties.Settings to something else and stop the Timer on Form 1.

If their is a simplest way let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The Error i thought is that you are showing the form2 before hiding the previous form.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var Form2 = new Form2();
     form1.Visible=false;
     Form2.Show();
}
```

You can also make form2 as modal by using show dailog method() by which focus is given to the form2 and form1 becomes inactive though it will be shown.

modal and modeless forms https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/aa984358%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Nope the error is that I can't hide the form in the Load event, that event fires because the form became visible. According to your answer I think showing the Form2 first would be more advice. Cause u showing something before hiding another one. You cannot eat an apple then take it. If this make sense.

Comment: why not make form2 modal

Comment: It won't make sense to my program I need to make the Form 1 Active Form ! so that when I close the Form 2 it shows back the Main form and make it able for me to close the entire software through Form 1

Answer (score -1):

You can use **Visible** property to hide your form.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var Form2 = new Form2();
    Form2.Show();
    this.Visible=false;
}
```

Comment: I think it's a good Idea. Setting `this.Visible=false;` won't keep the form on focus on the screen? Am just wondering. The Visible property isn't working as well.

Comment: @The_Little_Cousin An invisible control can't be focused. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus(v=vs.110).aspx